# Какое местоимение надо употребить для согласования?

Tags: местоимения

> Она держала бокал (так), словно в нем/в том плескалось жидкое пламя.

Когда мы должны употреблять *в том*, в каких случаях? Можно ли обойтись без *так*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что единственно правильным является следующий вариант: **Она держала бокал так, словно в нем плескалось жидкое пламя.**

1) **Это СПП с двойным значением: образ действия + сравнения**, указательное слово ТАК + сравнительный союз, без указательного слова это будет сравнительное придаточное, а оно не имеет смысла.

2) **Местоимение "в том" используется для обозначения ситуации**, а не конкретного предмета, например:  Она сидит да жалуется на всех, что ей скучно, как будто **в том** другие виноваты.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда в предложении "И что на банкет заказано, съедят и о том забудут. " "о том" -правильно?